# Oracle sql - stored procedure - concat a variable in a string

Tags: string, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, concatenation

I have a stored procedure of this kind

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE AAA 
(
    p_BBB       IN  VARCHAR,
    ...
)
AS 
T_QUERY varchar2(3000);
BEGIN
     OPEN A_CUR FOR SELECT ... BBB like '%' || p_BBB || '%';

   T_QUERY := 'SELECT BBB like %'|| p_BBB ||'% '; 

END AAA;
```

The problem is that while the first query is correctly processed, the concat between the strings in `T_QUERY` gives me error (*invalid character*).

Neither using `concat()` works, the `T_QUERY` will be pass to another stored procedure that performs the query.

Can anyone help me??

Comment: 'Select bb like '%data%'' - this string doesn't make any sense. You are missing 'from sometable where somecolumn like ...' part.

Answer (score 1):

you may try

```
T_QUERY :='SELECT BBB like ''%'|| p_BBB ||'%''';
```

Comment: That's a recipe for creating an SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @Codo So what is the best way to avoid SQL injection in this case?

Comment: The best way would be to pass the query and the parameter separately and to use bound parameters when executing it (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE p_query USING p_param). In addition, the execution plan will be cached that way. If a single query string is unavoidable, replace all single quotes with two single quotes, put a single quote at the start and at the end and run it through DBMS_Assert.Enquote_Literal. And read and adhere to [How to Write Injection Proof PL/SQL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/plsql/overview/how-to-write-injection-proof-plsql-1-129572.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Above solution is correct.
You use it like this.

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE AAA  
( 
    p_BBB       IN  VARCHAR, 
    ... 
) 
AS  
T_QUERY varchar2(3000); 

BEGIN 

     T_QUERY :='SELECT BBB .. like ''%'|| p_BBB ||'%'''; 
     OPEN A_CUR FOR T_QUERY ; 
     ----
     ----

END AAA;
```